# Import and create iPhoto Event from folder name

Tags: photos.app, automator, import

I would like to automatically import a folder to iPhoto (eg. with Automator). The Event Name should be the name of the folder with the images.

Is this possible with automator?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! To encourage others help you, you should try to show what you have done to solve the issue you are asking about on your own before posting here – see [ask] to get an idea of what is expected, and, generally, the [faq].

Answer (score 1):

In addition, this is the default behavior if you simply drop the folder onto the iPhoto icon. There is no direct need to make an Automator action unless you are doing this for many many folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

See below workflow that I did.

[image]

You may need to get the additional automator actions. You can get them here:

http://www.automatedworkflows.com

Comment: Which of the actions need to be bought from the referenced site? Can you think of alternative ways for these actions?

Comment: The first action "Get Information for Finder Items". Unfortunately it is only sold as a package. The only other suggestion is using applescript. But after I got the whole Finder Action Pack, I was able to do handle at least 10 different workflows that I wanted to set up.